# Reuse объектов вместо создания новых идентичных. Java

Tags: java, коллекции

Имеется текстовый файл, в каждой строке которого описано событие. Описание состоит из: даты, некоторого текста и страны. Мы парсим этот файл, так чтобы каждая строка преобразовывалась в такой класс.

```
public class Holidays implements Comparable<Holidays> {
    private Date date;
    private String name;
    private String country;

    public Holidays(Date date, String name, String country) {
        this.date = date;
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
    }
```

Потом объекты *Holidays* мы пихаем в *ThreeMap*.

*date*  и  *name* всегда уникальны, 
*country* часто повторяется.

**Вопрос:** как сделать так,чтобы при повторении страны не создавался новый объект *String country* для каждого *Holidays*, а использовался уже имеющийся(если такой уже есть).

Comment: Выглядит как экономия на спичках.

Comment: Пример естественно абстрагирован.

Comment: Это плохо, так как может привести [к проблеме XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)

Comment: Реализовал как в вашем ответе, все отлично. На будущее учту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выглядит как экономия на спичках, но, если вы уверены, что это вам необходимо (отпрофилировали приложение, убедились, что это - узкое место) вы можете сделать свой кэш строк:

```
public class StringPool {
    private final Map <String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public String intern(String s) {
        String exist = map.putIfAbsent (s, s);
        return (exist == null) ? s : exist;
    }
}

countriesPool = new StringPool();
```

и прогонять все считанные имена стран через него:

```
country = countriesPoll.intern(country);
// ... 
Holidays h = new Holidays(date, name, country);
```

---

<sub>PS. Сразу выкиньте морально устаревший класс `Date` и воспользуйтесь классами из пакета [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (для начала посмотрите `LocalDateTime`).</sub>

Comment: А не проще ли использовать джавовский пул строк?

Comment: Проще, но не лучше ) В докладе Алексея Шипилёва по ссылке из ответа @SergeyGornostaev  рассказано, почему.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать свой интернер. Вариант из доклада "[Катехизис java.lang.String](https://youtu.be/SZFe3m1DV1A?t=2003)" Шипилёва:

```
public class CHMInterner<T> {
    private final Map<T, T> map;

    public CHMInterner() {
        map = new ConcurentHashMap<>();
    }

    public T intern(T t) {
        T exist = map.putIfAbsent(t, t);
        return (exist == null) ? t : exist;
    }
}
```